# How to access cloned git repo in multi-stage docker build?

Tags: docker

I have a dockerised logstash and I want to add an additional plugin, [logstash-input-pulsar](https://github.com/se7enkings/logstash-input-pulsar).
The plugin needs to be downloaded via git clone, and its dependencies need to be installed using jruby:

```
bundle install
rake install_jars
```

I figured I could first use a git image to git clone the plugin, then use a jruby image to cd into the plugin folder and install the gems. However, I get this error when I try to cd into the plugin folder:

```
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to logstash-input-pulsar
```

The complete message when I try to build the Dockerfile is:

```
[logstash (master)]$ docker build -t logstash .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  70.03MB
Step 1/10 : ARG ELK_VERSION
Step 2/10 : FROM alpine/git
 ---> f54f496311fb
Step 3/10 : RUN git clone https://github.com/se7enkings/logstash-input-pulsar
 ---> Using cache
 ---> 93b473ae8753
Step 4/10 : FROM jruby:9
 ---> 4e5c810afeb7
Step 5/10 : RUN cd logstash-input-pulsar
 ---> Running in c1b9158d91d0
/bin/sh: 1: cd: can't cd to logstash-input-pulsar
The command '/bin/sh -c cd logstash-input-pulsar' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

And the Dockerfile is:

```
ARG ELK_VERSION

FROM alpine/git as intermediate
RUN git clone https://github.com/se7enkings/logstash-input-pulsar

FROM jruby:9
COPY --from=intermediate /logstash-input-pulsar /logstash-input-pulsar
RUN cd /logstash-input-pulsar
RUN bundle install
RUN rake install_jars

# https://www.docker.elastic.co/
FROM docker.elastic.co/logstash/logstash:${ELK_VERSION}
RUN echo 'gem "logstash-input-pulsar", :path => "logstash-input-pulsar"
RUN bin/logstash-plugin install --no-verify
```

I figured the `logstash-input-pulsar` folder doesn't persist once the git image is destroyed. Yet I'm not sure how I can chain these commands together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like the issue comes due to clone on the base image without a proper path.

You can try below Dockerfile and it should work.

```
FROM alpine/git as intermediate
WORKDIR /app
RUN git clone https://github.com/se7enkings/logstash-input-pulsar

FROM jruby:9
COPY --from=intermediate /app/ /app
WORKDIR /app/logstash-input-pulsar
RUN bundle install
RUN rake install_jars
```

Comment: This works thanks. If I want to access `/app/logstash-input-pulsar` in the last build command, can I just copy from intermediate again?

Comment: yes, you can copy the same way as we copied in the first layer.